# Utilize ['] key

Tags: interface, workflow, customization, shortcut

How to use the <kbd>'</kbd> key (next to <kbd>1 / !</kbd> key in English: ISO keyboard layout) within blender?

Normally you have to double press it to type it. For assigning and using the key this is not appropriate behavior.

[image]

Comment: huh? For me just pressing that key once produces `\`` as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue with the configuration of the keyboard layout in the OS, not related to blender.

Answer (score 0):

for me it's shift + the key to use it

Comment: For me Shift+grave accent/backtic key gives me a tilde: `~`

Comment: I think it depends on the operating system, and/or maybe my configuration is set differently or not correct. Have to press the shift + ´6' also twice to get '^' .

Comment: well ok then just thought that I could help

Answer (score 0):

**THE SOLUTION**

---

Changed the keyboard layout (not the keyboard model) into `English US with euro on the 5` .

With this wrong layout the `'` key does work. By doing so the key can be used within blender.

The problem has nothing to do with blender but seems to be an os configuration error.

(Now lets find the appropriate layout > It is strange; but with mentioned selected layout as wrong it does work correct and there is no euro on the 5 as.)

[threat can be closed]